# If $\sin x + \sin y = 1$ and $\cos x + \cos y = 0$, solve for $x$ and $y$

Tags: trigonometry

- $\sin x + \sin y = 1$
- $\cos x + \cos y = 0$

Any valid pair of $(x, y)$ is fine, as the restrictions on the board in the image below are obscured.

I got the question from chapter 26 of a comic called Yamada-kun.

[image]

How can I solve this equation?

Comment: $x=\pi/6$ and $y=5\pi/6$ works.  Just do trial and error on the unit circle

Comment: No, don't just do trial and error, be smart about it! Note that $\cos y = - \cos x$. This implies that $y = (2k+1)\pi \pm x$. Now feed both possibilities into the $\sin$ equation (one of them is inconsistent with it, but that may not be true in general), and pull out the solutions.

Comment: @stochasticboy321 This is essentially smart trial and error

Comment: noting geometric symetry isn't trial and error.  cos x = - cos y imply x and y are "essentially the same angle but for reflection across one or both axis" and that x and y are on quadrants on the opposite side of the vertical axis. As x and y are the same up to reflection sin x = +\- sin y so as sin x + sin y =1.  sin x = sin y = 1/2 and x,y = pi/6 up to reflection.  As sin x = sin y and cos x = -cos y they are reflected over the vertical but not the horizontal axes.  That limits it to (x,y) = {(5pi/6,pi/6),(pi/6, 5pi/6)}   Not trail and error.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

There is an interesting trick: you may couple the two equations by writing
$$ e^{ix}+e^{iy} = i \tag{1}$$
hence $e^{ix}$ and $e^{iy}$, that are two points on the unit circle, are simmetric with respect to the imaginary axis. By imposing that their sum has unit norm, we clearly get $\{x,y\}=\left\{\frac{\pi}{6},\frac{5\pi}{6}\right\}$:

[image]

Comment: you blew my mind in places i didn't know could be blown

Comment: This is a very insightful solution. +1 (I'd give more if I could).

Answer (score 3):

There are so many different ways to solve it the real question is which way.

What reaches out to grab me is:

$\cos x + \cos y = 0$

$\cos x = - \cos y$ which means either $y = \pi - x$ (within a period of $2\pi$) or $y = x + \pi$ (within a period of $2\pi$).

If $y = x + \pi$ then $\sin y = - \sin x$ and $\sin y + \sin x = 0 \ne 1$ which is impossible.

If $y = x - \pi$ then $\sin y = \sin x$ and $\sin y + \sin x = 2 \sin x$.  If this is so (and it's our only option) then $\sin x = 1/2$ which means $x = \{\pi/6, 5\pi/6\}$.

So $(x,y) = (\pi/6, 5\pi/6)$ or $(x,y)= (5\pi/6, \pi/6)$ (within periods of $2\pi$)

Comment: Simplest, most direct answer.

Answer (score 2):

**HINT**

Squaring both equations you get
$$
\sin^2 x + \sin^2 y + 2\sin x \sin y = 1\\
\cos^2 x + \cos^2 y + 2\cos x \cos y = 0
$$
Now add them together to get
$$
2 + 2 \sin x \sin y + 2 \cos x \cos y = 1
$$
or in other words
$$
\frac{-1}{2} = \cos x \cos y + \sin x \sin y = \cos (x-y)
$$

Comment: does this pick up the solution $\sin x + \sin y = -1$?

Comment: @jim this method has the potential to general some false solutions as well as the genuine, because the original equation was squared. One should plug the results back into the original equations to be sure it is actually a solution to the problem.

Comment: I think this is fine, you just have to observe the restriction that both $x$ and $y$ must be $\in [0, \pi] $ because that's where $\sin x$ is non-negative. We have $\sin x + \sin y=1$, and the maximum of $\sin$ is 1, so if we have any negatives at all we can't reach $1$

Answer (score 1):

There are identities for sum of sin and cos:

$$\sin(x)+\sin(y) = 2\sin\left(\frac{x+y}{2}\right)\cos\left(\frac{x-y}{2}\right)_.$$
$$\cos(x) + \cos(y) = 2\cos\left(\frac{x+y}{2}\right)\cos\left(\frac{x-y}{2}\right).$$

Using the first equation tells us that $\cos\left(\frac{x-y}{2}\right)\neq 0.$ Therefore by the second equation, $\cos\left(\frac{x+y}{2}\right) = 0.$

This may or may not be useful in finishing the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I will only look for solutions on $[0, 2\pi)$

We need to make $2$ observations:

$1)$ The maximum value of $\sin \theta$ is $1$. Therefore, if any of $\sin x$, $\sin y$ is negative, $\sin x + \sin y < 1$. It follows that both $x$ and $y$ must be $\in [0, \pi]$.

$2)$ $\cos x= -\cos y \iff \cos x = \cos (\pi - y)$ . (You can prove this using the [cosine subtraction formula](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/TrigonometricAdditionFormulas.html)). Since we are working only on the interval $[0, \pi]$, we must have $x=\pi-y$. This makes sense, because the cosines of symmetric angles on opposite sides of the $y$ axis will cancel out to $0$.

---

Substitute $x=\pi-y$ into the first equation:

$$\sin (\pi-y) + \sin y = 1$$

Using $\sin (a-b)= \sin a \cos b - \cos a \sin b$ we can deduce that $\sin (\pi-y)=\sin y$

$$\sin y + \sin y = 1$$

$$\sin y = \dfrac 12$$

$$y = \dfrac {\pi}{6}, y= \dfrac {5\pi}{6}$$

$$x=\pi-y$$

Therefore the solutions are $ \left( \dfrac {\pi}{6}, \dfrac {5\pi}{6}  \right)$ and $ \left(\dfrac {5\pi}{6}, \dfrac {\pi}{6}  \right)$. The symmetry of the solutions is expected, since both original equations and symmetric.

Answer (score 0):

$$\sin x + \sin y = 1\Rightarrow 2\sin\frac{x+y}{2}\cos \frac{x-y}{2}=1\\\cos x+\cos y=0\Rightarrow 2\cos\frac{x+y}{2}\cos \frac{x-y}{2}=0$$
It follows $$ \cos \frac{x+y}{2}=0\text{ and } \cos \frac{x-y}{2}=0\iff  $$ The first ($\cos \frac{x+y}{2}=0$) gives, from the first given equation,

$$\begin{cases}x+y=\pi\\x-y=\frac{2\pi}{3}\end{cases}\iff(x,y)=(\frac{\pi}{6},\frac{5\pi}{6})$$
The second  ($\cos \frac{x-y}{2}=0$) is discarded by incompatibility.

Thus the solutions are given by $$(x,y)=( \frac{\pi}{6}+2m\pi,\space \frac{5\pi}{6}+2n\pi)$$
It is not worthless to see the graphic solutions: all intersections of the red lattice, with blue closed curves.

[image]

Comment: I think you are missing the family of solutions  $\left(\frac{\pi}{6}+2n\pi, \frac{5\pi}{6}+2m\pi \right)$ since the equations are symmetric

Comment: I guess you say this because of the beautiful answer of Jack D'Aurizio. This is explained by the symmetry with respect to the two diagonals (don't forget that cosinus and sinus are functions even and odd respectively)

Comment: I don't know anything about complex numbers (except the definition of course) so I can't understand Jack's solution unfortunately. All I'm saying is that if $(x, y)$ is a solution, so is $(y, x)$. You can of course just find both families of solutions algebraically witouth relying on observing that the equations are symmetric

Comment: Note dear friend in the graph the symmetry respect to $y=x$. You have $(x,y)$ solution $\iff$ $(y,x)$ solution.

Comment: NOTE.- There are two proposed revised edition for this post, Takahiro Waki and Camichael. I appreciate very much the intention but I find it hard to understand that I do (because of my deficient English). Once I accepted with the help of someone but I saw that my mistake was only correcting typos but correction was in another direction. I appreciate much the intent, but I do not understand (I apologize).

Answer (score 0):

This is probably improper vocabulary but I think this concepts are fundamental.

Your "basic" angle is $0 \le \theta \le \pi/2$.  All other angles are "essentially" equivalent "upto reflection on one or two axes".  (Or up to periods of multiples of $2\pi$.)

Example.  $\theta$ and $\pi - \theta$ are "equivalent up to reflection on the y-axis" and $\sin \theta = \sin (\pi - \theta)$ and $\cos \theta = - \cos (\pi - \theta)$ and "sines change signs on reflection over x axis" and "cosines change signs on reflection over y axis".

$\theta$ and $\pi + \theta$ are equivalent "up to reflection on both axes" and $\sin \theta = - \sin (\pi + \theta)$ and $\cos \theta = - \cos (\pi + \theta)$.

Similarly for $\theta$ and $-\theta$ are equivalent "up to reflection on the x axis" and $\sin \theta = - \sin (- \theta)$ and $\cos \theta = \cos (- \theta)$.

.......
.......

Okay,  So $\cos x + \cos y = 0\implies \cos x = - \cos y$ means $x$ and $y$ are equivalent upto but reflected over the y-axis.

So $\sin x = \pm \sin y$ but $\sin x + \sin y \ne 0$ means $\sin x = \sin y$ meaning $x$ and $y$ are not reflected over the x-axis.

So $y = \pi - x$.

And now as $2\sin x= 2\sin y = 1$, the "basic angle" is $x|y = \pi/6$ and $y|x = \pi - \pi/6 = 5\pi/6$.